# Any CPU platform and X86 Platform

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, windows-7

I am really confused about target platform.  For best results, to make my application run on any CPU, what target platform should be used.  I tried Any CPU but my application does not run on Windows 7 with Access 2010 installed.  It returns an error

```
The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine
```

Someone told me to avoid this error, change platform to X86.  But I am unable to change that too.  Dropdown menu contains only Any CPU.

What to do?
Thanks

Comment: See if this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/3469dce8-3b3f-4897-b124-3f4393373ff1 helps you with x86.  Once you add the x86 option, target that platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get new platforms, you can go into configuration manager and add a new one, but I thought x86 was one of the default ones provided.  Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx) for you.  Quoted here in case MS moves their stuff around *yet again*.

> Here are common procedures for creating and managing solution build
>   configurations:
>
> To create a Solution Build Configuration
>
> Open the Configuration Manager dialog box.
>
> On the Active Solution Configurationdrop-down list, choose New.
>
> The New Solution Configuration dialog box opens.
>
> Type a name for the new solution build configuration in the Name text
>   box.
>
> To use the same settings as those specified for another solution build
>   configuration, choose one from the drop-down list for the Copy
>   settings from textbox.
>
> If you want to create one or more project configurations at the same
>   time, select the Create new project configurations check box.
>
> To rename a Solution Build Configuration
>
> Open the Configuration Manager dialog box.
>
> On the Active Solution Configuration drop-down list, choose Edit.
>
> The Edit Solution Configurations dialog box opens.
>
> Select the solution build configuration name you want to change.
>
> Select Rename, then type a new name for the configuration.
>
> To select and edit a Solution Build Configuration
>
> Open the Configuration Manager dialog box.
>
> Select the desired solution build configuration from the Active
>   Solution Configuration drop-down menu at the top of the dialog box.
>
> The Project Contexts panes display the properties of the active
>   solution build configuration.
>
> Select any project available in the solution.
>
> Select the desired project Configuration and Platform. Together, these
>   two settings specify the project configuration to be used.
>
> If the project is to be included when you build this solution build
>   configuration, select the Build check box.

Answer (score 1):

In your connection string, try replacing

```
    Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
```

with

```
    Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
```

Comment: Thanks ! I am not setting any connection strings.  These are being taken by the system when I add binding source and datasets etc.

Comment: Well, `Jet` doesn't work on 64-bit machines, which is why you are getting the error. About your problem with the target platforms, try tinkering with the Configuration Manager, there's got to be a way to make x86 appear. I don't have a copy of Visual Studio installed, can't check that for you.

Comment: somewhere in there is a connection string, whether you are binding to a DSN or specifying the provider yourself.